# Shopify: How to render products from collection, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, liquid

What I need: 
 click on collection title and run script to show first 8 products from this collection. 
The issue : if I use ajax request I think I can get produts in form of Json Object, smth like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:    "/collections/MyCollection?view=json",
    type:   'GET'
})
```

but I don't know how to transform Json Object item in form of liquid product and append it to my HTML div.

Comment: Add a success callback that logs the server response. Then go from there. Basically, iterate over the array and create and append HTMLElements. These are all invidual and basic problems, with lots of existing answers.

Comment: yeah, but if you move in way you proposed - I'll need to create my product cart from scratch - title take from json title, link from json and so on, but if we have ready snippet for product card and product as an object already in liquid - I think this is the longest way and less correct

Comment: Since liquid is server-side, my guess is you need to figure out a way to request liquid generated HTML from the server. Might be obvious but from your question it's hard to tell how much research you done so far.